# List Index Error in Python

Tags: python, search

In this program, I want to search for a `Number` from a list. When I search a number that is in the list, it works correctly.

But if I search a number that it is not in list, it gives me this Error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fourth.py", line 12, in <module>
  if(AranaElemean==liste[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range`

```
liste=[12,23,3489,15,345,23,9,234,84];

Number=11;
i=0;
Index=0;
isWhileActive=0;
while (i<len(liste) and Number!=liste[i]):
   i=i+1;

   if(Number==liste[i]):
      Index=i;
      isWhileActive=1;
   else:
      Index=0;


if(isWhileActive==0 and i!=0):
   print("Please Enter Valid Number.");
else:
   print("Index:",Index);
```

Comment: all of this could be replaced with `if Number in liste: ...`

Answer (score 2):

That's because i goes from 0 to len(liste) and inside the while loop you are increasing the i by one. So when it doesn't find the desired number and i gets the value i = len(liste), you increae it by 1 in the loop so you get the error because it exceeds the range of the list.

you can use the following

```
while (i<len(liste)):

   if(Number==liste[i]):
      Index=i;
      isWhileActive=1;
      break
   else:
      Index=0;
   i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be:

```
while (i<len(liste)-1 and Number!=liste[i])
```

This is because Python list indexing begins at 0.

Therefore, for a list of length *n* you need to index from 0 to *n-1*.